# TypeError at /ap1/checkbooks/ 'type' object is not iterable; return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes] TypeError: 'type' object is

Tags: python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am getting django Error while using rest django concept.
How to solve the below error of django i can't able to open the webpage in my browser.
please let me know how to solve the issue.All the codes are below. Any help appreicatable .
TIA

**Settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for pro1 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_=f2k%yr6l&3sbcz#dpt5ec8t+7aw_i^2p*$$z0kt0iq!u0iag'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'ap1',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pro1.urls'

'''
REST_FRAMEWORK={
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
       'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', # for restriction
  
    )
}''' # for restriction access


REST_FRAMEWORK={
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
}





TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pro1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import  BookSerializer
from .models import Book
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    #Below line to give token authority
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Book,BookNumber

class BookNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=BookNumber
        fields=['id','isbn_10','isbn_30']


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number=BookNumberSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model=Book
        fields=['id','title','author','number']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class BookNumber(models.Model):
    isbn_10=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    isbn_30=models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=True)


# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_publise=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publise_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False,blank=True)
    upload_time=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)#consider the current time.
    front_page=models.FileField(upload_to="content_folder/",default="")
    end_page_image=models.ImageField(upload_to="Image_folder/",blank=True)
    number=models.OneToOneField(BookNumber,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)#This line means only 1 isbn_10 & isbn_30 number will be assigned to one number in

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import BookViewSet

router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('books',BookViewSet)
urlpatterns=[
    path('check',include(router.urls)),
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
#Below import for token
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ap1/',include('ap1.urls')),
    path('auth/',obtain_auth_token),
]
```

**ERROR**
[image]

**TERMINAL ERROR**

```
 File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 146, in initialize_request
    request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 394, in initialize_request
    authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
  File "E:\d_project\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 272, in get_authenticators
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
[03/Jun/2021 15:01:48] "GET /ap1/checkbooks/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87380
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

You are missing the `,`

Comment: Hi! Do consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027465) this if it helped at all

Answer (score 0):

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model=Book
        fields=['id','title','author','number']
        depth = 1
```

The number is already the field in your Book model. You dont need to import it from BookNumber serializer. Just add depth =1  and it will show all fields.

Comment: The issue in the traceback shows in authentication classes. I dont think you have set default authentication class in your settings. Also, define only one permission class . You have defined two of them.